# Image Button not working in Emulator and PhoneGap - Ionic 2

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I have this class in my home.scss

```
.img_button{
    color: #fff;
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;
    background: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background-image: url("/build/images/lotus_button.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 200px auto;
    padding: 0 0 0 3em;
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

In home.html

```
<ion-content class="home" padding>
  <button class="img_button">Image Custom Button</button>
</ion-content>
```

It's working fine in the browser, but not in the `ionic emulate ios` or `phonegap serve`.

However, in the .img_button in home.scss I change background-image to url like this: `background-image: url("http://www.clker.com/cliparts/d/X/i/j/F/U/expences-button-png-hi.png");` It's working in all `ionic emulate ios`, `phonegap serve`, and in the browser.

I'm not sure of how to use my local path for background-image in scss.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally manage get it working by changing background-image from

```
background-image: url("/build/images/lotus_button.png");
```

to

```
background-image: url("../../build/images/lotus_button.png");
```

On the other case, if you want to use image path with img src use this:

```
<img src="/build/images/lotus_button.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be a bunch of things, the first thing I would do would be to [debug in Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) or [Safari](http://appletoolbox.com/2014/05/use-web-inspector-debug-mobile-safari/) and look at the console tab to see if there are any clear errors.  Next look at the Networking tab.  It could be anything from a whitelist issue to the image is not getting included with your build.